# Access nested list within a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

So I'm working on a lab studying multilayer dictionaries, the goal is to receive an input of a string including a country and three cities located in this country, i.e.
`string = "Spain Madrid Barcelona Valencia"`, then ask for an input (`city = "Madrid"`). If the city has been previously input, the output should be `Madrid is located in Spain`, otherwise the output should be `No data on input city`.

I've come up with the following:

```
country = "Spain Madrid Barcelona Valencia".split()
#Initialize a dictionary: 
d = {}
#Create another list that only includes cities:
cities_list = country[1:]
#Create a nested list within a dictionary:
d[country[0]] = cities_list
```

Which would provide a nested dictionary such as `{'Spain': ['Madrid', 'Barcelona', 'Valencia']}`

And that's where I get really confused. It's clear that I need to access the nested list, but using d.values() only gives the following output

```
dict_values([['Madrid', 'Barcelona', 'Valencia']])
```

I'm clearly missing some fundamental info on the topic, but I've looked up here and in Eric Matthes's "Crash Course" but still couldn't find a solid solution.

Probably my initial approach is completely wrong? There's a couple of similar topics here too, but it seems none of them actually involves not just accessing a list (which I kinda understand: d."Spain"[0]) but also comparing an input to one of the list's values.

Any advice would be great anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, to check if `Madrid` exists in your dictionary you can use for loop to check

```py
city_to_be_searched = 'Madrid'
result = None
for k,v in d.items():
    if city_to_be_searched in v:
        result = k
if(result):
    print(f'{city_to_be_searched} located in {result}')
else:
    print('No data found')
```

```
Madrid located in Spain
```

Answer (score 1):

After taking an input:

```
city_name = input()
```

You could do something like:

```
result = None
for key in d:
    if city_name in d[key]:
        result = f'{city_name} is located in {key}'

if result:
    print(result)
else:
    print('No data on input city')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over the key, value pairs of a dictionary using `items()` method as:

```
city = "Madrid"
found = False
for key, value in d.items():
    if city in value: # check if Madrid is in the values' list
        print(f"{city} is located in {key}")
        found = True
        break
if not found:
    print("No data on input city")
```

Output:

```
Madrid is located in Spain
```

Comment: If `d` is `{'India': ['Bombay', 'Kolkata'], 'Spain':['Madrid', 'Barcelona', 'Valencia']}` then there will be No data found